# Redirecting URLs when launching a new website - how to avoid dropping page rank

Tags: seo, search-engines, htaccess, url-rewriting, search-engine-indexing

i have over 100 urls in my website which i need to redirect:

E.g.

- `/page/how-to-bake-chocolate-cookies/` will redirect to `/cookies/how-to-bake-chocolate-cookies/`
- `/page/contact/` will redirect to `/contact-us/`

and so on...

I want to make sure search engines will catch the new url without affecting my site's quality, ranking, etc...

How can I best accomplish this and avoid users experiencing 404 errors and make sure Google will correctly index my new pages?

Comment: Welcome to the site Joanna, what kind of webserver do you use - if you don't know, could you share a link with us?

Comment: I am using LAMP (apache, php, mysql, centos)

Comment: just a comment. If you're doing this for SEO purposes... don't.  An "SEO expert" recommended we do this a few years ago, and it involved a lot of programming changes, and doing all those 301 redirections. When finished, we still lost page rank for a few weeks, and after that, the improvements (if any) were negligible. Basically, it's not worth it for an existing site.

Comment: @Rodolfo - so you're claiming that nothing is better than something? Yours is the first recommendation NOT to undertake this activity despite every search engine and search professional recommending that it IS what you should do...

Comment: @Rodolfo You're correct, it doesn't always preserve your pagerank intact that depends on the SEO of the new site, but it does ensure that your existing users can find the site and don't just get 404's

Comment: what I'm saying is, the effort, loss in pagerank, and time involved doesn't make up for the (alleged) gain in SEO "value". For an (alleged) gain of .0000001 value you're losing weeks of pagerank, lots of time of development, risk of breaking things, etc.  And from personal experience, definitely the change is not noticeable at all. In fact, I've checked with other SEO companies and they say that basically, for a new site, do it, but for an existing site it's not worth it.

Comment: I don't understand why a new site would need to employ such redirects (especially 100 of them). If it's a new site, then no one (including search engines) is linking to either of the URLs. So just use the URLs you want to be canonical, and be done with it. No one is going to arbitrarily type `/pages/...` into their browser.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use 301 redirects in your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file, the 301 code signals to google that the url has been permanently redirected.

I'd also recommend signing up for [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and submitting a [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) to them, if you haven't already, as this will help them to understand the changes you're making to your site.

```
redirect 301 /old-url http://www.yoursite.com/path-to/new/page.html
```

[This article from teknocrat](http://www.teknocrat.com/htaccess-301-redirect-examples.html) and [this query](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=htaccess+301+redirect&hl=en&tbo=1&output=search&source=lnt&tbs=qdr%3ay&sa=X&ei=sRovT5X9NOfT0QWD2_WtCA&ved=0CAsQpwUoBQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=955) should give you some more information

Comment: If possible, the redirects should be put in the server config files, as that's more efficient.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat which files are you referring to? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't remember which one when I posted. I've checked and it's `apache2.conf`, or depending on your setup another file included from there such as `sites-enabled/yoursite.conf`. The rules usually go inside a `<Directory>` section.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat got you - I plumped for .htaccess as most users on shared hosting don't have access to higher level files.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to speeding along the respidering and re-caching of the site consider running Google Adwords to the new pages (even if it’s a small budget $100/$200) – effective, usually cuts revisit time 50% or more.